# Inherit methods from a base class in Cython

Tags: python, inheritance, cython

I have the following Cython class that holds a C++ class `CPP_Holder`(declared in a `.pxd` file) as a class attribute

```
cdef class CythonHolder:
    cdef CPP_Holder holder

    def __cinit__(self, int parameter):
        self.holder = CPP_Holder(parameter)

    def get_param(self):
        return self.holder.param

    [other methods]
```

Since I have a group of similar classes (like `CythonHolder`) that all have methods such as `get_param`, I imagine it would be possible to introduce a base (or mixin) class, similar to the conventional Python approach, to allow these holder classes to inherit these common methods, 
i.e.,

```
cdef class CommonMethods:
    def get_param(self):
        return self.holder.param 
    [other methods...]

cdef class CythonHolder(CommonMethods):
    cdef CPP_Holder holder

    def __cinit__(self, int parameter):
        self.holder = CPP_Holder(parameter)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile as the error complains that `self.holder` is not defined in class `CommonMethods`. As a newbie to Cython, I am aware of that the `cdef class` behaves differently from the conventional Python ones. But, is there a mechanism that allows this simple inheritance to be implemented?

Comment: Either all `holders` are of type `CPP_Holder` (or inherited from it/its parent class) then you can put it into `CommonMethods` or you rely on duck typing, which isn't possible for static typing (which is triggered for `cdef`-variables/members).

Comment: @ead Could you please substantiate on "or inherited from it/its parent class"? My thought was more on letting ``CythonHolder`` hold the C++ class and inheriting methods from a mixin class ``CommonMethods``. Since you said this isn't possible as C++ class is statically typed, I am wondering if introducing a statically typed parent class (to C++ holder) in ``CommonMethods`` would be viable.